# Merge Sort Code Not Giving Desired Output

Tags: c++, mergesort

I have just started to learn recursion. The problem is of merge sort, I was trying to solve it without breaking in two arrays so i am passing the start index (si) and end index (end).

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

void inputArray(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void printArray(int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void mergeArray(int a[], int si, int end)
{
    int mid = (si + end) / 2;
    int size = end - si + 1;
    int temp[size];
    int index = 0, i = si, j = mid + 1;

    while (i <= mid && j <= end)
    {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
        {
            temp[index] = a[i];
            index++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[index] = a[j];
            index++;
            j++;
        }
    
    }

    if (i > mid)
    {
        while (j <= end)
        {
            temp[index] = a[j];
            index++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (j > end)
    {
        while (i <= mid)
        {
            temp[index] = a[i];
            index++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    //Copying Content Of Temp Array Back To Original Array
    int k=0;
    for (i = si; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = temp[k];
        k++;
    }

}

void mergeSort(int a[], int si, int end)
{
    if (si >= end)
    {
        return;
    }

    int mid = (si + end) / 2;
    mergeSort(a, si, mid);
    mergeSort(a, mid + 1, end);
    mergeArray(a, si, end);
}

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    inputArray(a, n);
    mergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);
    printArray(a, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry For The Long Code, It fails for cases like: `6 5 4 3` (Array In Descending Order) but works for other case like `6 5 4 9`

I am trying to debug this code since yesterday, can someone please help me

Comment: Well, what did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: To be honest, i can't find any mistake now. I just know that it isn't working when i give it a descending array as an input, in rest of the cases it is working fine.

Also in descending only the first two digits are not coming as expected, rest of it is also fine.

I have tried printing out the array at different stages of the code but still i can't figure out the issue

Comment: Are you familiar with a "debugger"?  Did you step through your code, when it fails, line by line in a debugger?

Comment: Any bad assumptions made while writing will probably be followed through into any examination you make of the code. The debugger doesn't care about your assumptions. It shows you what the compiler made of the code. Typical usage is to step through the problem area in the code line-by-line looking for the unexpected, such as the wrong path taken or the wrong value computed. The unexpected shows where your assumptions and the program generated truth deviated. Resolve the discrepancy and carry on.

Comment: FYI, `int temp[size];` is a Variable Length Array (VLA) and not supported in Standard C++.  Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @DrewDormann actually i am not familiar with the debugger, saw few videos on youtube but still can't figure out. I just manually dry run the code with the help of pen and paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed It, Thank You Everyone!

```objectivec
      #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    void inputArray(int a[], int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cin >> a[i];
        }
    }
    
    void printArray(int a[], int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    void mergeArray(int a[], int si, int end)
    {
        int mid = (si + end) / 2;
        int size = end - si + 1;
        int temp[size];
        int index = 0;
        int i = si;
        int j = mid + 1;
    
        while (i <= mid && j <= end)
        {
            if (a[i] <= a[j])
            {
                temp[index] = a[i];
                index++;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[index] = a[j];
                index++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    
        while (j <= end)
        {
            temp[index] = a[j];
            index++;
            j++;
        }
    
        while (i <= mid)
        {
            temp[index] = a[i];
            index++;
            i++;
        }
    
        index = 0;
        for (i = si; i <= end; i++)
        {
            a[i] = temp[index];
            index++;
        }
    }
    
    void mergeSort(int a[], int si, int end)
    {
        if (si >= end)
        {
            return;
        }
    
        int mid = (si + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, si, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid + 1, end);
        mergeArray(a, si, end);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int a[100];
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        inputArray(a, n);
        mergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);
        printArray(a, n);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void merge(int arr[], int start, int mid, int end) {
    int n1 = mid - start + 1, n2 = end - mid, a1[n1], a2[n2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n1; ++i) a1[i] = arr[i + start];
    for(int i = 0; i < n2; ++i) a2[i] = arr[mid + 1 + i];
    
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = start;
    
    while(i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if(a1[i] < a2[j]) {
            arr[k++] = a1[i++];
        }
        else arr[k++] = a2[j++];
    }
    
    if(i < n1) arr[k++] = a1[i++];
    if(i < n2) arr[k++] = a2[j++];
}

void mergeSort(int *arr, int start, int end) {
    if(start >= end) return;
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
    
    mergeSort(arr, start, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, end);
    merge(arr, start, mid, end);
}
```

Try this logic

Comment: Actually this approach i have already tried, but i wanted to do it without splitting in two arrays

Comment: Merge sort is a divide and conquer algorithm. Which basically means splitting the input array for  desired output.

Comment: Ya that's fine but i didn't wanted to split it in two different arrays in the merge function rather i wanted to use the indexes si to mid (1 sorted array) and mid+1 to end (another sorted array)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-merge-sort/

refer this